# SecTrustEvaluateWithError leads to UI unresponsiveness

Tags: swiftui

In my code I am using this function

```
func checkIsError(someDate: Date) -> Bool {
    var someError: SomeError?
    guard SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &someError),
          someError == nil else {
        return false
 }

 return true
}
```

When I run application and open file in which is that function I am getting

*This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness.*

I tried using *DispatchQueue.global.async()* but when I am using that I can't return value from Void function (in my case false). Is there any option I don't run *SecTrustEvaluateWithError* on main thread without and return false when it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the method itself on the background thread. Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    if !self.checkValidation(yourDate) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showPopupOrSmth()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SecTrustEvaluateAsyncWithError` instead of `SecTrustEvaluateWithError`

Answer (score 0):

both answer have correct details, but

1. not call on background queue but
2. on some  `.userinteractive` and use `SecTrustEvaluateAsyncWithError`
3. dispatch the result on the main thread

So a lot of threading to implement. Else you get rare and strange crashes.